# react-boilerplate npm install error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, flux

I follow work flow from [flux official tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/todo-list.html)

and try to build simple template project from [react-boilerplate](https://github.com/petehunt/react-boilerplate)
but when I use `npm install`, many error occured ..

I select some piece of output below

```
> node-gyp rebuild

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:6:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:339:13: error: no member named 'New' in 'v8::String'
    return  _NAN_ERROR(v8::Exception::Error, errmsg);
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:319:50: note: expanded from macro '_NAN_ERROR'
# define _NAN_ERROR(fun, errmsg) fun(v8::String::New(errmsg))
                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~^
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:343:5: error: no member named 'ThrowException' in namespace 'v8'
    _NAN_THROW_ERROR(v8::Exception::Error, errmsg);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:324:11: note: expanded from macro '_NAN_THROW_ERROR'
      v8::ThrowException(_NAN_ERROR(fun, errmsg));                             \
      ~~~~^
```

...

```
    /Users/mengwenqiaoxindongcom/.node-gyp/4.2.1/include/node/v8.h:2933:3: note: 'New' declared here
  static Local<Object> New(Isolate* isolate);
  ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/mengwenqiaoxindongcom/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:270:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 14.5.0
gyp ERR! command "/Users/mengwenqiaoxindongcom/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.1/bin/node" "/Users/mengwenqiaoxindongcom/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/mengwenqiaoxindongcom/pra/javascript/react-full_stack/flux/react-boilerplate/node_modules/jsxc/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v4.2.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@0.2.1
envify@0.2.0 node_modules/envify
├── through@2.3.8
└── falafel@0.2.1 (esprima@1.1.0-dev)
```

I find some solve that changing node version between `v0.12.7` and `v4.2.1` but error also exit.

```
nvm ls
        v0.12.7
->      v4.2.1
        system
node -> stable (-> v4.2.1) (default)
stable -> 4.2 (-> v4.2.1) (default)
iojs -> N/A (default)
```

finally, I follow this [issue](https://github.com/facebook/flux/issues/282) and notice that nobody could correctly solve these error.

could somebody help me? thanks ..

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled upon your question when searching for a solution to the same problem. Just checked the [issue](https://github.com/facebook/flux/issues/282) you linked to and finally managed to find a solution. You might have seen it too already, but if not, someone suggested the following which worked for me:

- Remove `node_modules` folder
- `npm install jest-cli --save-dev`
- `npm install`

The problem was that `jest-cli` expected a lower version of Node. So updating `jest-cli` seemed to resolve the issue.